# Why is ggfortify failing with this 2 time series plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I am having trouble with a single plot of 2 time series using the GGfortify package.

I run into a problem on the last line.  Is there a correction that can be made?

```
library(Ecdat)
inflation <- as.numeric(Mishkin[, 1])

data_ts <- ts(inflation,start=c(1950,2), frequency = 12)

AR_data <- arima(data_ts, order = c(1,0,0))

AR_data_fitted <- data_ts - residuals(AR_data)

combined <- cbind(data_ts,AR_data_fitted)

gg <- autoplot(combined, columns = c(1,2),cmain = "Inflation Data")
```

Comment: Just remove `, columns = c(1,2)` will give you the required plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
library(ggfortify)

combined <- cbind(data_ts,AR_data_fitted)

colnames(combined) <- c("Original Data", "AR fitted data")

autoplot(combined,main = "Inflation Data",facets = FALSE)
```

[image]

## Update

```
autoplot(combined,main = "Inflation Data",facets = FALSE)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to get both series into one plot.  The answer seems to be to add "facets = FALSE".

Comment: A further question - how do I pick 2 different colours for the two series in the plot?

Comment: See my updated answer. Don't forget to accept it as answer to your question by clicking the √ below upvote or downvote button.

Comment: Will do - but any advice on how to also change the colour of the 2 time series?  Say to blue and black?